# Can iarbuild run in parallel mode?

Tags: gnu-make, iar

I am using iarbuild in command line to build my projects on a 8-core PC. The build speed is quite slow and it smells the multicore PC's is not fully utilized. Is there a build option that can make the build running in parallel mode? (Like in GNU make, there is a -j option)

Comment: At least iarbuild in EW 5.40 which I have doesn't have it, but it's somewhat old now. I have found that best way to make compilations faster is to minimize file includes; that is, not have one include file, which includes all other include files. Each compilation unit should only include header files it needs, to minimize header file opening and parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an email from IAR last week

**New version of IAR Embedded Workbench for ARM**

Version 7.40 is now available

•   Parallel build

The compiler can now run in several parallel processes to better use the available processor cores in the PC. To control parallel build, choose Tools>Options>Project>Enable parallel build.

I believe that this is also becoming available for other targets as I have seen similar for the MSP430.